# landscape mode video activity is restarting

Tags: android, video, landscape

I am playing videos in my app, video should play portrait and landscape mode withought restarting actvity, please any can give examples are links.

- using video view for playing video.

  ```
  public class PlayVideoActivity extends Activity {

  private VideoView video;
  private ImageButton back;



  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
      setContentView(R.layout.main);


      back = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.backbutton);
      back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

          public void onClick(View arg0) {

              finish();
          }
      });

      video=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);



      video.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
      video.setDrawingCacheQuality(VideoView.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);

      video.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://"+ getPackageName() +"/" + R.raw.fillings_class_1));
      video.requestFocus();
      video.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
      video.start();

  }


     @Override
     public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
         //restore the relevant information

     }



  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to prevent the activity from being restarted on an orientation change, you need to set the `configChanges` attribute for the Activity in the manifest to include `orientation`.